# How to install Windows on my Ubuntu netbook from USB if BIOS does not support booting from USB?

Tags: grub2, windows, usb, bios

I have a netbook running Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to put Windows 7 on it (which I have on USB). However, **my BIOS doesn't have booting from USB as an option**. It only has HDD, LAN and FDD.

I can't figure out a way to boot from my USB... Could I somehow use GRUB?

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to do is install Plop Boot manager. Plop boot manager is a small program that allows you to boot from all of your computers available devices, including a USB, even if your BIOS doesn't support it. Download the Plop boot manager ISO from [here](http://www.plop.at/en/ploplinux/download.html). Be sure to choose the right version of Plop boot manager. If you are unsure about choosing the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version, choose the 32-bit version. Now, you need to configure Grub2 to boot from the ISO file you downloaded. In a terminal, run `gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`. Paste in the following text below the `exec tail` line.

Code:

`menuentry "Plop Linux ISO" {`

```
    echo Loading Plop Linux
    set isofile="/iso/ploplinux-4.2.2.iso"
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/syslinux/kernel/bzImage vga=1 iso_filename=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/syslinux/kernel/initramfs.gz
```

`}`

Replace **/iso/ploplinux-4.2.2.iso** the the location of your downlaoded ISO file. Save the file and close gedit. When you reboot your computer, choose the Plop Linux ISO item from the Grub2 menu. Finally, select plop boot manager from the Plop menu, plug in your USB, and select the USB option to boot from your USB!